# Using Glyphicons in an ASP.NET MVC app that has Bootstrap Bundled

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that includes bootstrap. My directory structure looks like this:

```
/
  /App_Start
    BundleConfig.cs
  /Content
    app.css
    bootstrap.min.css
  /Fonts
    glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
    glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

I need to bundle Bootstrap in my app. In my BundleConfig.cs file, I have the following:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/public/bundles/css")
    .Include("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")
    .Include("~/Content/app.css")
  );

  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/public/bundles/scripts")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
  );
}
```

When bundling is turned OFF, everything renders fine. When I turn bundling ON, everything renders fine, *except* for the font icons. When I look in the console window, I see 5 404 errors related to the font icons. Its like its trying to reference the font files like the following:

http://localhost:9090/public/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

Yet, they do not exist in the public directory. I'm not sure how to remedy this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the fonts are referenced using a relative URL:

```
../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

Your CSS bundle is served from a URL in the folder `~/public/bundles/`. Since the relative URL only specifies a single "parent folder" navigation, the font URL ends up as `~/public/fonts/...`.

There appear to be three options:

1. Update the font URLs in the `bootstrap.min.css` file to use `../../fonts/...` - you'll need to remember to re-apply that change every time you update the Bootstrap files;
2. Change your bundle URL to have the same folder depth as the CSS file - something like `~/public/css`;
3. Add [a `CssRewriteUrlTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.cssrewriteurltransform(v=vs.110).aspx) to your bundle. This will re-write the relative URLs to absolute URLs.

Eg:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/public/bundles/css")
    .Include("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
    .Include("~/Content/app.css")
);
```

Comment: Note the .min. in the answer. Your file _must_ have `.min.` in the path or `CssRewriteUrlTransform` doesn't work. See the annoying bug described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619086/cssrewriteurltransform-is-not-being-called I wasted a _lot_ of time on this