# CssRewriteUrlTransform not being called on non-minified CSS

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, web-optimization

I'm trying to replace file paths inside CSS files. I tried the example [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765238/cssrewriteurltransform-with-or-without-virtual-directory#19765418):

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

        IItemTransform cssRewrite = new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper();
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css/Components")
            .Include("~/Content/Components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css", cssRewrite)
            .Include("~/Content/Components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.structure.css", cssRewrite)
            .Include("~/Content/Components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.css", cssRewrite)
            .Include("~/Content/Components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css", cssRewrite)
            .Include("~/Content/Components/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css", cssRewrite)
        );
    }
}

public class CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper : IItemTransform
{
    public string Process(string includedVirtualPath, string input)
    {
        return new CssRewriteUrlTransform().Process("~" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(includedVirtualPath), input);
    }
}
```

For some reason only the last two minified files trigger the `Process()` method. When I use their non-minified versions, then none of the files go through `Process()`. This behavior is the exact opposite of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619086/cssrewriteurltransform-is-not-being-called#19817114).

How do I get `CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper.Process()` called for every file?

Comment: I had the same problem. Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50064258/6081130) answer.